# Copy worksheet in Epplus Values only

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using Epplus to copy a worksheet from a wokbook and paste it in another workbook.I can able to copy the worksheet sucesssfully,by using the below code.

```
  ExcelPackage masterPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\\Users\\350154\\Desktop\\vb workouts\\testsample.xlsx"));
  ExcelPackage pckg = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\350154\\Desktop\\vb workouts\\as.xlsx"));
  string workSheetName = pckg.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Name;
   ExcelWorksheet pck = pckg.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
   pck.ConditionalFormatting.RemoveAll();
   masterPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(workSheetName, pck);
```

The code copies the sheet sucessfully.But the copied sheet has formulas in their cells.So Values not copying in a new excel pls help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking to copy the values from one spreadsheet into a new sheet in another, try this:

```
public static void CopySheetValues(string sourcePath, string sheetName, string destPath)
{
    using (var src = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(sourcePath)))
    using (var dest = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(destPath)))
    {
        var wsSrc = src.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName];
        var wsDest = dest.Workbook.Worksheets[wsSrc.Name] ?? dest.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(wsSrc.Name);

        for (var r = 1; r <= wsSrc.Dimension.Rows; r++)
        {
            for (var c = 1; c <= wsSrc.Dimension.Columns; c++)
            {
                var cellSrc = wsSrc.Cells[r, c];
                var cellDest = wsDest.Cells[r, c];

                // Copy value
                cellDest.Value = cellSrc.Value;

                // Copy cell properties
                cellDest.Style.Numberformat = cellSrc.Style.Numberformat;
                cellDest.Style.Font.Bold = cellSrc.Style.Font.Bold;
                // TODO... Add any additional properties that you may want to copy over
            }
        }

        dest.Save();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Sample code updated to show how formatting can also be copied from the source to the destination worksheet

Comment: Its working at the same time how to apply the format painter from  source sheet to destination sheet

Comment: Pete Its Great ,Thank You ,But i cant able to copy the background color of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Pete. But I found a way to copy an entire worksheet to another workbook while I was looking for a different issue. https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/94

You change the below line to add the worksheet to the workbook.

```
var wsDest = m_GeneratedHeader.Workbook.Worksheets[wsSrc.Name] ?? m_GeneratedHeader.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(wsSrc.Name, wsSrc);
```

No need to use the two 'for' loops to iterate through rows and columns to copy each property. Adding the worksheet will copy cell style, font style, merge cells, etc... Worked for me.

Note that this was introduced after EPPlus 4.5.0.1