# How to copy an excel worksheet from a file to another using EPPlus for .NET

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Given the following scenario:

- I have a source.xlsx file with multiple worksheets (worksheet1, worksheet2, workshToCopy, etc) and I generate the destination.xlsx based on another .xlsx template file that has different worksheets than the source.xlsx. I want to add a worksheet from the source file to the destination file.

For now I was able to add an empty worksheet to my destination file like this:

```
if (FileExists(outputFile) && FileExists(inputFile))
{
  var inputPackage = new ExcelPackage(inputFile);
  var outputPackage = new ExcelPackage(outputFile);

  var summaryInputWorksheet = inputPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[ExcelSummaryHelper.SummaryWorksheet];
  outputPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(summaryInputWorksheet.Name);
  outputPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveToEnd(summaryInputWorksheet.Name);
  outputPackage.Save();
}
```

What's the best approach to copy the content of workshToCopy from source.xlsx to destination.xlsx's new worksheet using the EPPlus library ?

Comment: There's an [Add overload](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheets.cs#L203) that acceps a source ExcelWorkSheet. Have you tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy worksheet in Epplus Values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582359/copy-worksheet-in-epplus-values-only)

Comment: The duplicate question shows how to copy an entire sheet including formatting and asks how to copy only the data

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Yes! you're right and it works. I don't know why I haven't seen it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved.

There's an overload for the Add method on the ExcelWorksheets class that looks like this:

```
ExcelWorksheets.Add(string Name, ExcelWorksheet Copy)
```

Can't believe I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just clone the existing one?

```cs
ExcelWorksheets clonedWorksheet = currentExcelWorksheet.Clone();
```